# Pattern match all text between two sets of pattern

Tags: regex

I have been trying to create a Regular expression which will match a text block between two sets of pattern but havent been able to do so, at most I just get one line of text.

The text block can contain a sequences of "####" or "****". the number of repetitions is min 2

For example the block text might look like this

```
************
test 1
test 2
test3
############
x1
x2
x3
############
a1
a2
a3
*****
b1
b2
b3
***********************
c1
c2
c3

######################

d1
d2
d3
```

Regex match groups should be able to give me all the blocks

result needs to look like this:

```
Block1:

test 1
test 2
test3

block 2:

x1
x2
x3

Block 3:

a1
a2
a3

block 4:
b1
b2
b3

block 5:
c1
c2
c3

block: 6
d1
d2
d3
```

My effort so far looks looks like this:

Regex: `^.*#{2,}\s*(.*)(?=$)|^.*\*{2,}\s*(.*)(?=$)`

the fiddle with relevant text: https://regex101.com/r/ghgNbs/1/

Any help would be really great!

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/mYoYd4/1

Comment: wow....thanks mate

Comment: I posted an answer with 2 options and explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a lazy dot matching pattern with a DOTALL modifier that will look like

```
(?sm)^(?:!#{2,}|\*{2,})\s*(.*?)(?=^(?:!#{2,}|\*{2,})|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QSWfm5/2)

**Details**

- `(?sm)` - DOTALL and MULTILINE modes on
- `^` - start of a line (due to `(?m)`)
- `(?:!#{2,}|\*{2,})` - either `!` followed with 2 or more `#`, or 2 or more `*` chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (what you need): any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=^(?:!#{2,}|\*{2,})|\Z)` - a positive lookahead that requires

  - `^` - start of a line (due to `(?m)`)
  - `(?:!#{2,}|\*{2,})` - either `!` followed with 2 or more `#`, or 2 or more `*` chars
  - `|` - or
  - `\Z` - end of string.

However, the pattern will be rather resource consuming, and it is advisable to unroll it. I suggest

```
(?m)^(?:!#{2,}|\*{2,})\s*(.*(?:\R(?!(?:!#{2,}|\*{2,})).*)*)
```

Note: no DOTALL modifier this time. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QSWfm5/1).

**Details**

- `(?m)^(?:!#{2,}|\*{2,})\s*` - same as above
- `(.*(?:\R(?!(?:!#{2,}|\*{2,})).*)*)` - Group 1 (your expected result is here):

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (the whole line)
  - `(?:\R(?!(?:!#{2,}|\*{2,})).*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `\R(?!(?:!#{2,}|\*{2,}))` - a line break (`\R` may be replaced with `(?:\r\n?|\n)` and similar) that is not followed with `!` and 2+ `#`s or 2+ `*`s
    - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (the whole line)